# TCPDF font spacing too wide

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I have this code that has worked in the past:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'In', 'LETTER', true); 
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);    
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);    
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',11);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetLeftMargin(0.5);
$pdf->SetLineWidth(.04);
$pdf->Rect(.5, .5, 10, 7.5);
$pdf->SetLineWidth(.01);
$pdf->Rect(.55, .55, 9.89, 7.39);
$pdf->setFont('Times', 'BI', 31);
$pdf->SetXY(0.5,0.9);
$pdf->Cell( 9.75, 0.5, 'Certificate of Completion',0,1,'C');
$pdf->setFont('Helvetica', 'B', 11);
$pdf->SetXY(0.5,1.75);
$pdf->Cell( 9.75, 0.2, 'Course Work or Training in Infection Control',0,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell( 9.75, 0.2, 'Approved by', 0, 1, 'C');
$pdf->Cell( 9.75, 0.2, 'The New York State Department of Health &', 0, 1, 'C');
$pdf->Cell( 9.75, 0.2, 'The New York State Department of Education', 0, 1, 'C');
```

Now the output looks like this:
[image: Bad PDF]

I tried adding this:

```
$pdf->setFontSpacing(100);
```

but the script failed to execute.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The version of TCPDF on the site was old.

I updated to the latest version and the problem went away.